# OperationalError at /admin/login/ no such table: django_site

Tags: django, django-admin

When I try go to the `admin/login` I get error.

`OperationalError at /admin/login/
no such table: django_site`

**settings**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```

**migrations**

```
account
 [X] 0001_initial
 ...
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 ...
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 ...
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
sites
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_domain_unique
```

**console**

```
./manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

[Traceback](https://dpaste.de/d36O)

How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already added 'django.contrib.sites' to your INSTALLED_APPS, then you should run migrate to create the required table into your database.

python manage.py migrate